# Rendering forms through django-crispy-forms in python

Tags: python, django

We need to render forms in python and capture the html output. So far we're resorting to a dirty hack:

```
def crispy_page(form):                
    mini_template = """                          
        {% load crispy_forms_tags %}                 
        {% crispy form %}                            
    """                                          
    from django.template import Template, Context
    t = Template(mini_template)                  
    c = Context({"form":form})                   
    return t.render(c)
```

We'd like to just be able to get the rendered output directly from crispy forms somehow, without having to hop through the django templating system. Any thoughts?

Comment: do you have a helper? do you have a layout ? what is exactly the use case? Why do you need HTML in Python if I can ask, there might be better ways to customize output.

Comment: I do have a helper and a layout. The use case is twofold.
1) I want to test form html output.
2) I want to have a form contain a subform. So, in python, I want to render the subform down to html, and then inject that html into the container form where the subform-field is located.

Answer (score 4):

[These are the lines](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/blob/dev/crispy_forms/templatetags/crispy_forms_tags.py#L109-118) in the node for the `{% crispy %}` tag for rendering a form with a helper + layout. I could refactor those out, so that they are easy to be called from outside. The application wasn't thought to be used server side, that's why it's so rigid for that.

It's my understanding that you have some fields of a form A, then fields of another form B and then more fields of form A, is that right?

**EDIT 2012/7/30**

Version 1.2.0 will come with a `render_crispy_form` function that solves your issue:
https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/issues/64#issuecomment-7354910